# Rules, rules, rules... still not enough!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

I hadn't gotten a letter from any of my friends in a while, so I was quite surprised when I received one from my companion, O. He usually only contacts me when he has a problem, so I was quite hesitant to read even the envelope, for fear of its contents. However, once I was certain the message wasn't a bomb in disguise, I was delighted to find that his predicament was a relatively simple one.

> To: Dopplegamer
>
> From: O
>
> ---
>
> I need your help. As the result of a lot of sudden downsizing and agents conveniently taking vacation days, the job of finishing development of the company's new board game has landed solely on me. I've managed under the intense pressure so far, but I've hit a snag: A part of the game is missing.
>
> The difficulty is, I don't know what.
>
> The following is everything that I am legally able to show you about the game (and a little more). It probably won't make much sense out of context, but there is nothing to be done about that. Could you please be a pal and find out what's missing?
>
> ---
>
> **Game Rules (incomplete list):**
>
> - The class of Bounty Hunter can only be unlocked after stage seventy-five has passed.
> - The amount of players can be modified mid-game, but only if the most experienced player at the table approves.
> - Certain game constructs can be marked in order to keep the game organized. The categories the constructs are organized by shall be decided by the players.
> - A character's profile within the game should reflect the personality of their player in real life, as to prevent confusion.
> - An inspection of the rules is to be offered to new players in order to ensure that the game's rules are fully understood.
> - If any game rules are not specified before the start of the round, a player must go to the game's center for help on any clarifications.
> - Every player who is able can vote on whether to increase or decrease the total level of the stage, but if they prove they cannot handle this entitlement, it will be taken from them.
> - If any of the actions of the other players in this game are unclear or can be improved, the collaboration of two other players can be used to change that action.
> - If the action of another player goes against the rules, it can be disregarded and cancelled by more experienced players.
> - For additional information about the rules and concepts of the game, go to our self-contained [Wikipedia page](https://RedHerring.com).

When I finished reading the note, I actually laughed out loud, thinking that O must be joking. There is an integral part to the game that is never mentioned even once, despite the fact that without it, the entire thing is worthless! But with O's deadline fast approaching, tell me:

***What is missing from the game?***

Comment: "There is a tag that is missing from this question, but it will be added after a correct answer has been found."  -Spoiler Prevention System (SPS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules of the game resemble

> Stack Exchange

*The class of Bounty Hunter can only be unlocked after stage seventy-five has passed.*

> One needs 75 rep to set a bounty.

*The amount of players can be modified mid-game, but only if the most experienced player at the table approves.*

> Not sure what this refers to.

*Certain game constructs can be marked in order to keep the game organized. The categories the constructs are organized by shall be decided by the players.*

> Tags can be applied to questions. The tags are unique to each Stack Exchange site.

*A character's profile within the game should reflect the personality of their player in real life, as to prevent confusion.*

> User can create unique recognizable profiles, names, and avatars.

*An inspection of the rules is to be offered to new players in order to ensure that the game's rules are fully understood.*

> Offers to "take our tour"

*If any game rules are not specified before the start of the round, a player must go to the game's center for help on any clarifications.*

> The meta Stack Exchanges.

*Every player who is able can vote on whether to increase or decrease the total level of the stage, but if they prove they cannot handle this entitlement, it will be taken from them.*

> Users can upvote and downvote questions and answers.

*If any of the actions of the other players in this game are unclear or can be improved, the collaboration of two other players can be used to change that action.*

> This could be approved edits.

*If the action of another player goes against the rules, it can be disregarded and cancelled by more experienced players.*

> Questions can be closed. Answers can be deleted.

*For additional information about the rules and concepts of the game, go to our self-contained Wikipedia page.*

> [Stack Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange)

*What is missing from the game?*

> Not sure, but there was no mention of puzzling so I would say the Stack Exchange game needs Puzzling.

Comment: This answer is close enough to be counted, but for the record, the overarching answer was supposed to be (ROT13) Pbzzhavgl, nf vg gur bar guvat gung FR pna'g shapgvba jvgubhg.

Comment: rot13("Gur nzbhag bs cynlref pna or zbqvsvrq zvq-tnzr, ohg bayl vs gur zbfg rkcrevraprq cynlre ng gur gnoyr nccebirf." Ol 'zbfg rkcrevraprq hfre' vf zrnag n zbqrengbe, naq gur ahzore bs cynlref pna or zbqvsvrq jura n zbqrengbe fhfcraqf bar.)

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget rot13(V jnf evtug nobhg ercynpvat gur zbfg rkcrevraprq hfre jvgu "zbqrengbe", ohg qvqa'g haqrefgnaq gur "Gur nzbhag bs cynlref pna or zbqvsvrq zvq-tnzr", cneg vg vf abg punatvat gur nzbhag vg vf nobhg fhfcraqvat bar, creuncf "cynlre trgf xvpxrq bhg"?)